# token concatenation with defined symbols C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This macro is not expanding as I thought it would, I have the following macro (source is from Analog Devices so I cannot change this):

```
#define SRU(out,in)         \
    r0=dm(in##_REG);        \
    r1=sru_mask(out,in);    \
    r0=r0 and r1;           \
    r1=sru_field(out,in);   \
    r0=r0 or r1;            \
    dm(in##_REG)=r0;
```

Normally you would use it as

```
SRU (LOW, DAI_PB14_I);
```

But I want to create a HW configuration header so I defined:

```
#define DTS_SEL_DSP_I     DAI_PB14_I
```

So the usage above would be:

```
SRU (LOW, DTS_SEL_DSP_I);
```

But I get the error

```
error: identifier "DTS_SEL_DSP_I_REG" is undefined
```

it should be "DAI_PB14_I_REG"

So the macro is stringifying the actual symbol and not the value I defined, how can I get around this?

Comment: But you *can* change it. Add `#undef SRU` followed by your new definition, `#define SRU(out, in) ...`, into one of your own header files.

Comment: Heed the compiler: "DTS_SEL_DSP_I_REG" is not defined. When you call `SRU (LOW, DAI_PB14_I)`, the compiler expects DAI_PB14_I_REG, and it finds it somewhere.

Don't you need to have DTS_SEL_DSP_I_REG declared somewhere similarly to DAI_PB14_I_REG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the macro is stringifying the actual symbol and not the value I defined

Yes, this is the specified behavior for the token pasting operator.  Its operands are *not* macro-expanded before being pasted together.  If the pasted-together result is a macro name, then it will be expanded on the rescan.

> , how can I get around this?

Since you cannot modify the `SRU` macro, the best workaround would probably be to wrap it, which should be very simple:

```
#define MY_SRU(out,in) SRU(out,in)
```

Since they are not operands of the `##` or `#` operator, the arguments to `MY_SRU` will be fully macro expanded.  The resulting invocation of `SRU` with expanded arguments is itself expanded on the rescan.